# Why JsonConverter.WriteJson() never gets called, although JsonConverter.ReadJson() does get called?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

Why my custom JsonConverter.WriteJson() method doesn't get called ?

```
class MyType{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DocumentXamlDeserializer))]
    public string GuiData { get; set; }

    public string SimpleString;
}
```

Although the `ReadJson` does get called:

```
public class DocumentXamlDeserializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Gui.Handler.SerializeData());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var xaml = reader.Value as string;
        Gui.Handler.DeserializeData(xaml);
        return xaml;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(objectType); }
}
```

The serialization call: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataModel, Formatting.Indented);`

The deserialization call: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(raw);`

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  WriteJson is called, but ReadJson is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is because `GuiData` is null... I guess I could specify:

```
TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
```

But I want to serialize only `GuiData` even if it's null (I set its value during serialization), without serializing all null-properties... well, if I don't find better way, I guess I'd have to suffice with it...