# Newtonsoft WriteJson() is not being called, but ReadJson() is

Tags: c#, json.net

Please note: I read [Why JsonConverter.WriteJson() never gets called, although JsonConverter.ReadJson() does get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759441/why-jsonconverter-writejson-never-gets-called-although-jsonconverter-readjson) but it was unsatisfactory answer.

I have a JsonConverter. ReadJson is called and works great, but WriteJson is never called. Nevertheless, serialization happens just fine. While this is fantastic in the short term, I fear that some circumstance will eventually call my WriteJson and something will blow up.

I'm using JsonConvert.Deserialize, with a new JsonSerializerSettings object, to which I am providing a list of Converters. There are 3 converters. In the first two, WriteJson and ReadJson are called exactly as I expect (they deserialize decimals and ints, so I can handle commas and currency symbols). The third, which serializes a typeof Enum (based on an int), just does not call WriteJson, and yet the json writes out just fine (in fact, exactly as I want it to).

I have overridden CanWrite to return true, but I don't think that's the issue.

How do I force my JsonConverter to use MY WriteJson method?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't describe your code, edit your question and include the actual code you are using and a small runnable Main function we could copy and paste and run our selves that demonstrates the write not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Re-read my own question and figured it out. I'm only using my custom formatter when I'm calling Deserialize and passing in my formatter in a new settings object, so it makes sense that WriteJson() isn't called.

Using the formatter in an Attribute on the property invokes the methods properly.